# Automatic Nuget package restore in Visual Studio Online fails

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I've verified that it works locally by deleting all of the packages from the packages folder, opening up visual studio and then building my project - all of the packages are downloaded first and then it builds.

I do not have a .nuget folder and in the visual studio options I've allowed Nuget to download missing packages.

When building using TFS I get a ton of errors that I do not get when building locally. I believe this to be related to

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when building a new project with Visual Studio Online and **found this solution** :

1. In VS enable Nuget Package Restore (rt click on solution in solution explorer)
   [image]
2. **Remove** solution */Packages* folder from both local workspace *and* Visual Studio Online Version control.  *[(Thanks Robert)](http://robertgreiner.com/2013/09/team-foundation-service-build-error-nuget/)*
3. Confirm build works locally
4. Check-in changes: 3 Nuget files & modified .sln and .csproj
5. trigger build

NuGet should restore the local packages when you build and will also restore after VSO build.  Version control will not have a packages folder, but the required packages end up on the release server.  I trigger a release manager with each build and deploy with DSC.

NuGet documentation ( [*1*](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)  & [*2*](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated) )doesn't explain how that works and I've had to 'toggle' this on & off once to get builds to work after.  I've emailed support@nuget.org to ask for more detail and clearer documentation.

Comment: This doc explains a little more, but seems not to go into detail about how it actually works, it's a start https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

Comment: This is the old way, on the nuget site and in blogs they tell you not to use this.

Comment: That's correct and the package-restore link, says that too.  The hard to find bit to find referenced (at least by scanning docs) is the step to remove the package folder from source control prior to TFS/VS build.

Answer (score -1):

You should not have to checkin packages to source control. But you'll need to help MSBuild restoring that.

Check this link: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build

The trick is the MSBuild .proj file you have to create and reference there your solutions.

Nuget 2.7 is required